# After dropping database, its data is still on the hard drive

Tags: postgresql, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-20.04

Hey all on StackoverFlow!

I have a problem with my database. The company that I work for uses fixtures to populate the database for the development environment, and I do too. Sometimes these fixtures are not enough to see and test things and I needed real data. They provided me a `.dump` file to use that instead the fixtures. I started the restoration process with this:

```
rails db:drop
rails db:create
pg_restore -v -O -j 12 -U my_username -d my_database dump1234.dump
```

I needed to stop the process *(it was very time consuming - the* `.dump` *is ~37 Gb)*, and went back using fixtures for a while (I was waiting for the right moment when I could restore the dump again). I noticed that it got like ~100 Gb from my SSD already, but I didn't really care since I have plenty of space.
A week ago I finally managed to have some freetime, so I started restoring again with the same command. Again it was very slow, so I set a timer for windows (for 8 hours) to turn off and went to sleep. The next day I realized that something went wrong and I couldn't display my models on `localhost:3000`. So when I want to see a page eg.: `Houses#show` no models are displayed there. Same goes for any db table.

My tables looked like this:

```
     Name     |    Owner     | Encoding | Collate |  Ctype  |   Access privileges   |  Size   | Tablespace |                Description
--------------+--------------+----------+---------+---------+-----------------------+---------+------------+--------------------------------------------
 my_database  | karajaganaj  | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 |                       | 250 GB  | pg_default |
 postgres     | postgres     | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 |                       | 8529 kB | pg_default | default administrative connection database
 template0    | postgres     | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +| 8377 kB | pg_default | unmodifiable empty database
              |              |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres |         |            |
 template1    | postgres     | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +| 8529 kB | pg_default | default template for new databases
```

I decided to drop `my_database` with pgAdmin4 and I chose the delete/drop option there, when clicking on the database. On terminal in postgres console it disappeared too and I thought now everything is fine, until I checked my SSD and it **still** had the space occupied *(~250 Gb)*.

It looks like this **now** (after dropping `mydb_dev` and running `rails dev:env:reset` to repopulate the DB with the fixture data):

```
                                                                   List of databases
     Name     |    Owner     | Encoding | Collate |  Ctype  |   Access privileges   |  Size   | Tablespace |                Description
--------------+--------------+----------+---------+---------+-----------------------+---------+------------+--------------------------------------------
 my_database  | karajaganaj  | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 |                       | 27 MB   | pg_default |
 postgres     | postgres     | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 |                       | 8529 kB | pg_default | default administrative connection database
 template0    | postgres     | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +| 8377 kB | pg_default | unmodifiable empty database
              |              |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres |         |            |
 template1    | postgres     | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +| 8529 kB | pg_default | default template for new databases
              |              |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres |         |            |
```

I use:

- Ubuntu 20.04 (with WSL 2 on WIN10)
- PostgreSQL 14.4

How could I remove the space occupied from my SSD? I really want a fresh start with my databases and I also want to remove the extracted DB data from my SSD its just I have no idea where to find it and how to delete it.

**EDIT:**
The problem was after deleting the database I was not getting the space back that was taken up by the removed files.

The answer to my question:
[here](https://superuser.com/questions/1606213/how-do-i-get-back-unused-disk-space-from-ubuntu-on-wsl2)

Comment: Consider [Factory Bot](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) as an alternative to fixtures and dumps.

Comment: We use FactoryBot on the testing environment, but honestly I don't get to decide in this situation :D

Comment: You're a dev. Could you add FactoryBot to the dev environment?

Comment: "*My tables looked like this*" Those are not tables, those are databases. What might have happened is you deleted all the tables from my_database but since the database still exists Postgres held onto the disk space. Try `drop database my_database` to truly drop the database. If you want to keep the database, try `vacuum` to recover the space.

Comment: I certainly can add it, in fact it was already added.

Comment: Before assuming it's Postgres that's using the space, have you [confirmed what's using the space](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37221/finding-files-that-use-the-most-disk-space)?

Comment: Hmm. Looks like you are right. I'll update the question when I can fully confirm that the solution I'm trying, worked.

Comment: It did work! Thanks for the help. It made me thinking where is this extra unused space is and I found the answer. I probably didn't ask google the right questions.

Comment: Great! Rather than editing your question with the answer, go ahead and [answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), even if it's just referencing another answer; maybe expand upon how you determined that was the right solution to the problem. Then others who come upon this question can find the answer, and you'll get some points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned my edit:
The problem was after deleting the database I was not getting the space back that was taken up by the removed files. After @schwern's comment I realized that Ubuntu itself is taking that much space on my SSD. After some research I found [a question which roughly described my problem](https://superuser.com/questions/1606213/how-do-i-get-back-unused-disk-space-from-ubuntu-on-wsl2). The [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/1612289) helped me understand my situation more deeply.

Besides that, there is an open [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4699) on Github on this and between the comments, I found this [gem](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4699#issuecomment-1136319012), about how to do the process.
Also you have to make sure that Hyper-V features are installed as described [here](https://superuser.com/a/1307442), in order to not recieve an error message in PowerShell.